# audio recording in html with cross browser capability using only javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser, audio-recording

Can some help me on recording an audio file to get blob of audio file as output in all browser 
using only html and javascript.
I have tried using getusermedia of Html5 but it does not work on safari and some other browser.
With recorder.js to record audio file ,i am unable to get blob as output.

Comment: Please provide code samples of what you tried and why you think it isn't working

Comment: http://caniuse.com/stream

Comment: i have tried and the code is working on chrome fine using getusermedia  but not in any other

Answer (score 0):

Try WAMI! It uses recorder.js and flash to record audio from browser.

http://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/

Comment: i read about wami recorder , but can you suggest where i can get blob output of recorded file in the code.